# Use windows session credentials as login?? How does it work??

Tags: java, windows, authentication, windows-authentication

I came across programs like ARCserve HA, which use windows session credentials as the login without having me to manually type in the userID and password. How does this work?? The program is actually capable of getting my window's userID and password??

As my current project which is written in Java requires me to do something similar which uses the windows session credentials as login.

Could anyone provide me with any directions on how should i go about doing this? Any directions will be greatly appreciated.

*EDIT*

Maybe i should also include that ARCserve HA launches IE, from there i check the option "*windows session credentials*" as login. Hopefully this additional info might help.

Kevin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When Windows is part of an active directory domain it uses [Kerberos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_(protocol)) to perform authentication and single sign for services.

Take a look at [Spnego](http://spnego.sourceforge.net/) for integrated Windows authentication in Java.
Take a look at [this link](http://beamdocs.fnal.gov/DocDB/0015/001502/001/index.html) if you want to understand how Kerberos works a little better.

Bottom line, Kerberos passes a ticket around and never sends your password.  Once you login at the Windows login screen a ticket is created and you can pass that around to login to other resources.  This is why once you login you do not need to authenticate when you access a network share.  The ticket system also prevents your password from being stored in RAM.