# Windows system login credential

Tags: java, php, windows, mysqli

An php application which required an authentication details as same as windows system. i.e windows login credential and application credentials are same. I need to develop a php application that should automatically logged in with php after a windows successfully logged-in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way to get the *clear text* credentials used to log in on Windows. However, if the server on which the PHP application runs is in the same domain as the client machine, it should be possible to use Kerberos tickets or NTLM authentication (the latter might work also without the server being in the same domain as the client machine, but probably requires to use MSIE as client browser) to forward the credentials without explicitly having the clear text password. Several questions mentioned this, for example:

- [How do I access Windows credentials from Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126684)
- [Use windows session credentials as login?? How does it work??](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464229)
- [How to automatically login to the site using system credentials?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084554)
- [Use Windows authentication as login credentials for intranet applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14881997)